# Dotnet integration test can't find the service in docker-compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a docker file called `service1dockerfile` using asp-netcore 3.1 and my service is up and running.
If I build and run this same dockerfile after binding to port `5000`, I could do the curl and get the results back from `http://localhost:5000/welcome`

However, if I use the same dockerfile in docker-compose like below in order to use the integration test for service1. Then, I'm getting error `System.Net.WebException : Name or service not known Name or service not known`

docker-compose:

```
services:
    sevice1:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Service1dockerfile
       
        ports: 
            - 5000:80
        networks: 
            - my_network
    
    integrationtests:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: IntegrationTestDockerfile
        entrypoint: dotnet test --logger trx --results-directory /var/temp
        volumes: 
            - ./integrationtests/:/var/temp
         depends_on: 
            - sevice1
        networks: 
            - my_network
networks: 
    my_network:
```

my integration test looks like this:

```
[Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://service1:5000/welcome");

            WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Assert.IsNotNull(myWebResponse);
            Assert.True(true);
        }
```

and `IntegrationTestDockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

COPY . ./app
WORKDIR /app/src/Service1.IntegrationTests
RUN dotnet restore
```

After executing `docker-compsoe up` not only it throws the error  `Name or service not known Name or service not known` but also I can't connect to `curl http://service1:5000/welcome`. Can anyone point me to what is I'm doing wrong here that I can't connect to servic1?
This is the complete error message:

```
integrationtests_1  |   X Test1 [109ms]
integrationtests_1  |   Error Message:
integrationtests_1  |    System.Net.WebException : Name or service not known Name or service not known
integrationtests_1  |   ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Name or service not known
integrationtests_1  |   ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Name or service not known
integrationtests_1  |   Stack Trace:
integrationtests_1  |      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
integrationtests_1  |    at Service1.IntegrationTests.Tests.Test1() in /app/src/Service1.IntegrationTests/Tests.cs:line 19
integrationtests_1  | --HttpRequestException
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
integrationtests_1  | --SocketException
integrationtests_1  |    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
integrationtests_1  | Results File: /var/temp/_390f0681f55f_2021-07-27_09_57_46.trx
```

Comment: If the test project is also part of the docker-compose, then you should not be using service1:5000, you should be using `service1:80` because 5000 is the port of the host machine.. and the test container is not going to connect to the host machine but will connect to the service1 using the network `my_network` and host is not part of it.

Comment: No. it is a separate service that's the whole point of bringing in compose file. However, I also initially thought of the same, and I did everything with 80. still had the same issue. If you will see the error, it saying `Name or service not known` so I think it can't resolve the name called `service1`

Comment: If you run `docker ps` command do you see the container up for `Service1`? Can you share contents of `Service1dockerfile` ? is `my_network` a custom configured network? Did you try using the default network?

Comment: yes, I see the container name as `service1` when I do the `docker ps` and my network is the standard default bridge network.